# Question about argument principle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

> Let $f,g$ be holomorphic on a neighborhood of $\overline{D(0,1)}$. Assume that $f$ has zeros at $P_1,...P_k \in D(0,1)$ and no zeros on $\partial D(0,1)$. Let $\gamma$ be the boundary circle of $\overline{D(0,1)}$ traversed counterclockwise. Compute: $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}g(z) dz$.

I know I have to use the argument principle.

Suppose $a \in D(0,1)$ then $f(z) = h(z)(z-a)^k$, and therefore $\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=kh(x)(z-a)^{k-1}+h'(x)(z-a)^k$.

Thus, this means that $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{k}{(z-a)}+\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}$

Apparently it is the case that $Res(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}g(z))=kg(a)$. Here are my questions. Why is the last part true, and is this it? Do I need to show more justification? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by last part?

Comment: That $Res(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}g(z))=kg(a)$

Comment: That's correct. You have $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} g(z) = \frac{kg(z)}{z-a} + \frac{h'(z)}{h(z)} g(z) $. Since $\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)}$ is holomorphic near $a$, the integral of this term will be zero by Cauchy's theorem. And the integral of $\frac{kg(z)}{z-a}$ will give Cauchy's integral formula for $kg(z)$ around $a$.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. Thank you!